# .htaccess RedirectMatch Syntax

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having a heck of a time trying to get the syntax correct on a 301 redirect. I've researched online quite a bit but as I am completely new to this it just isn't clicking for me. I hope someone here can help.

I'm typing to write a rule that will change all links using the following format:

http://www.example.com/yyyy/mm/dd/page-name

To

http://www.example.com/category/page-name

In the above example, "/yyyy/mm/dd/" are variable for any number of dates.  It's a Wordpress migration and the new theme does not allow us to preserve the day and name format for permalinks, we are trying to preserve several years' worth of SEO "link juice."

For various reasons I would prefer to do this using a 301 Redirect instead of as a Rewrite. Thanks in advance!

EDIT to add:  Here is my attempt at it, I think I have mixed syntax for rewrites and redirects (among other things):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /category/$4/
```

Comment: Can you please share your contents of your configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have gotten it working with this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/category/$1/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks to everyone who replied, it helped me narrow things down at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /category/$4 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This is redirecting to the blog archive page (www.example.com/category/) which is about as far as I could get it to work. It's either not picking up the $4 back reference or the other rewrite rules are being applied or something similar.

Comment: can you post your whole `htaccess` file

Comment: My original htaccess file is in my first post.  I took the rewrite rule you suggested and replaced the following line; RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: @igotid32 - The rule should not replace `. /index.php [L]`, it should prepend it. So place it before that rule. In order, you'll have the two conditions to skip files and directories, then you'll have the new rule (as in this answer, line 3), and then your rule for `index.php`.